How can I help my broken avocado sprout?

I planted an avocado sprout and it was broken by accident. I tried to keep it together it with toothpicks and before I used something to wrap it but it does not look good. Could you suggest to me what to do to fix it? Do I need move it into the ground?

By broke, you don't mean the pit split as it always does, do you?

thank you so much you answer quickly make me feel more ok but this one i bring the seed from German to Thailand so i worry. and it was broken then i moved to change and this one already one week i little bit worry because because it from this one and i compose it again. i will keep it and send it again.

Before you get your hopes up about the Avocado, be aware that Avocado's don't grow true to type, so it is unfortunately unlikely that if the avocado does fruit (and it may take 10 years, it may never fruit) it is unlikely to be like the parent Avocado.  Also, avocado's can't tolerate freezing temperatures - especially the cultivars that grow in Thailand)

It has a root which is feeding off the seed so you don't need to do anything.  If the half of the seed starts rotting in water then remove it.  Otherwise, watch and wait is best as avocados take a while.
Repot in tropical soil mix when the root is a few inches long and you are good to go.

The OP thought the pit broke, not knowing avocado grows that way.
